# Thesis sometimes creates unwanted empty pages

Tags: overleaf, subsection, emptypage

I am currently using this thesis template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/iit-bombay-unofficial-latex-ph-dot-d-thesis-template/fybkvhqjqqsf .
In the appendix, for some reason, it creates sometimes empty pages. For example:

```
\section{A}
\subsection{A.1.}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{A table}
\resizebox{\width}{!}{\input{myinput}}
\label{A1}
\end{table}

% Created an unwanted empty page

\section{Results}
\subsection{Results 1.1.}
\subsubsection{Results 1.1.1.}
```

What I cannot understand is that sometimes, it creates an empty page after the end of a section or subsubsection, and other times, it does not create. Is there a way to avoid overleaf creating unwanted empty pages?

Comment: it is impossible to run your example to see the problem but _by design_ `[H]` will produce ugly white space, as latex floats tables to avoid bad page breaks and the purpose of `[H]` is to disable the float mechanism, so you may need to move the table or add new words by hand to get good page breaks.

Comment: Actually, just removing the ```[H]``` permitted to solve the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to run your example to see the problem but by design `[H]` will produce ugly white space, as latex floats tables to avoid bad page breaks and the purpose of `[H]` is to disable the float mechanism, so you may need to move the table or add new words by hand to get good page breaks.